# How can I add background color to datatable search box and select box

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am working with jquery-datatable and want to add a background color to the select box and the search box. So it looks like the header with the same background color.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#users').DataTable();
})
```

How can I pass the attribute to the datatable to change the background color of 
the select box and the search box?

Comment: Don't do this using Javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How your headers looks like depends on which CSS theme you are using (default, jQueryUI, bootstrap, foundation) so cant tell exactly what color you need. But to change the `background-color` for the length menu and search box use the below CSS and replace "red" with the color you want :

```css
.dataTables_length select {
   background-color: red;
}
.dataTables_filter input {
   background-color: red;
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/rw27Lz11/**

Comment: thanx for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Below css fixed my page.
For Select

```
.dataTables_wrapper 
     div.dataTables_wrapper 
         div.dataTables_filter select {
     color: white;
     background-color: red;
}
```

and For Label

```
.dataTables_wrapper 
     .dataTables_length, div.dataTables_wrapper 
         div.dataTables_filter label, 
         div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_info {
     color: white;
     background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this for new seekers and not really for the original question asker since the question is so old.  I played around with each of the above answers and none of them individually helped me fully.  I ended up creating my own solution from a mixture of what the different answers suggested.  This code will give you control of the search box color and the number of entries drop down list.  I selected white background with black text but you can obviously modify it to match whatever color scheme you want.

css code:

```
/* sets the datatables search box and count selector to white background with black text*/
.dataTables_wrapper 
        div.dataTables_length select,
        .dataTables_wrapper 
        div.dataTables_filter input {
     color: black;
     background-color: white;
}
```

you also have to have this javascript code at the bottom of your page:

```
// apply datatable in the HTML table
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#yourtablename').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove black outline in search input field in angular datatables

1. Please find the style file path in node_module file

like: `\node_modules\datatables.net-dt\css\jquery.dataTables.css`

2. Please find the path "`.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input{}`" and add changing

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue just before. I tried the code posted above and that not worked. Then I tried this, and work it:

```
.dataTables_length select  {
    background-color: white !important;
 }
 .dataTables_filter input  {
    background-color: white !important; 
 }
```

Just add `!important`